# How to stop TYPO3 from stripping <p> tags from RTE content (or touching it at all)

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.1.x

I have a TYPO3 which strips any `<p>` tags from content I create when the RTE editor is enabled for the field in question before it saves it in the DB. And it seems I cannot find a way to disable this behavior with a TypoScript. As soon as I disable the RTE editor I can save `<p>` tags and they get correctly rendered in the frontend. They also get correctly rendered in the frontend when I simply add them directly in the database in the tt_content table in the bodytext field.
When I switch to the edit source mode of the RTE I see all `<p>` tags in place. Before and after a save (also they never make it to the DB) so it looks like they get converted to (linux) line breaks or something and get converted back to `<p>` tags when the editor loads them in the backend. But those line breaks of course have no effect to in the frontend.

I thought this behavior would be controlled by `RTE.default.proc` but everything there looks good to me (p is already in the allowed tags and there is no clue why it could be stripped). I've also tried to disable the `RTE.default.proc.entryHTMLparser_db` and `RTE.default.proc.exitHTMLparser_db` as I wouldn't mind it if the HTML content as you see it in the edit source mode of the RTE (so with RTE still enabled!) would not be touched at all - in fact I would prefer it - but this had no effect. On the other hand when I add tags to the allowed tags which weren't there before (like `<button>`) this works so the things I try to add to `RTE.default.proc` aren't ignored in general.

So how can I stop TYPO3 from stripping my `<p>` tags from RTE content or touching it at all? I'd prefer a solution with TypoScript but meanwhile I would also be happy about an ugly hack in a sys extension as long as it works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a bug or not but the solution to my problem lies in `p.rmTagIfNoAttrib = 1`. At least in my TYPO3 version (v6.1.7 and nearly only built in extensions) I cannot find this setting in the preset TypoScript of the page or the RTE editor so I'm guessing it defaults to `0`. In my logic `0` means `false` so I'd say the default would read as "remove tag if there is no attribute?: no!".

However TYPO3 seems to work after its own logic. Adding the following statement to the page TS sloves my problem and `<p>` tags are preserved:

```
RTE.default.proc {
    entryHTMLparser_db {
        tags {
            p.rmTagIfNoAttrib = 1
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reasons for this behavior [are explained in the TYPO3 manual](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/Rte/Transformations/Introduction/Index.html#hybrid-modes):

> Many of the transformations performed back and forth in the TYPO3 backend date back to when it was a challenge to incorporate a RTE in a browser. It was then sometimes needed to fall back an a simple `<textarea>` **where rich text had to be presented in a simple enough way so that editors could work with it with no visual help.**

Comment: How does this explain why `p.rmTagIfNoAttrib = 1` preservers the `<p>` tag while `p.rmTagIfNoAttrib = 0` (like I would have thought and explained why above) doesn't? ...and furthermore how is this 'answer' trying to answer my original question?

Comment: It gives additional information, it does not answer your question.